Deallocation for NSTextView in Objective-C
I am learning to create a Cocoa application on Mac OS and have run into an issue with memory I don't quite understand. From what I've read with non-ARC is that you should be releasing anything you've allocated manually.
However, I am running into issues with some classes not deallocating after being allocated and initialized. For example, NSTextView, if I manually try to release it, it will not deallocate.  I am testing this by using my own implementation and overriding the dealloc function. As far as why, I plan to have my application be able to open and close Windows for debug and test suite runs; so I want to be able to destroy and remake the NSTextView with the Window if needed. However, I don't want to be leaking things when Windows are remade.
@implementation MyCustomTextView

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"MyCustomTextView deallocated");
    [super dealloc];
}

@end

With my code being something like this:
    @autoreleasepool { 
        self.textView = [[MyCustomTextView alloc] init];
    }

Then after callinge [self.textView release]; to release it my dealloc function does not get called. However, if I call [self.textView release]; twice, then it will trigger the deallocation. Why is that?
It doesn't seem to do it with many classes, just a few, but most classes seem to call dealloc after one release call. Shouldn't it be 1:1 release for each allocation to get a deallocation? I know refcounts can increase due to internal behavior, but that they should be freed when the original allocation is released. It doesn't seem like the solution should be to trace the internals of a class to determine how to release it.
It seems like either I'm doing something wrong or I am missing something, any help is appreciated!

Is self.textView a strong property and retaining the text view? What happens when you do self.textView = nil;?

It is a strong reference. It does deallocate if I set the textView to nil, but only if I release it first.

Are you using Objective-C as some sort of archaeological / historical exploration? This seems an odd way to "learn to create a Cocoa application".

This question is similar to: A developer when going through a code base encounters two different syntaxes for creating a NSString with the given integer. (implemented in MRC). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

This question is similar to: In Objective-C MRR, if foo is a retain property, then self.foo = [[Foo alloc] init] will need to be released immediately?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
